# PostSharp dependency sprawl

Tags: c#, nuget, postsharp

I defined a custom attribute 'attribute' in a library 'Lib' that I use to annotate a method 'method' in a project 'Service'. However, when unit testing 'method' (in a distinct unit test project that holds a reference to 'Service' to depend on it), I am getting :

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'attribute' from
> assembly 'Lib'.

Why?

I tried adding a updated the dependency on 'Lib' of the unit test project, which solves the exception. However, I do not understand why it has to be updated, I thought the reference to 'attribute' could be encapsulated in 'Service' without requiring projects depending on 'Service' to upgrade 'Lib' version as well

Asked in a more abstract and generic way: is it possible to annotate the outermost layer of a code base (say, the HTTP api facade of a service), or will PostSharp annotations only work if the consumer of an API depends of the attribute class itself.

I am fairly new to C#, so I am not sure if this is a PostSharp feature, a c# dependency management feature, or a mix of both. Seems dependencies are not transitively resolved, but still, I don't expect the unit test project to directly depend on 'attribute', even though it calls a method annotated with it

Comment: How are you referencing PostSharp? If you use `PackageReference` in your .csproj file (which is the default way of referencing NuGet packages nowadays), the library reference should be transitively included if you are not doing something explicit like `PrivateAssets="all"`.

Comment: @DanielBalas I am referencing it via <PackageReference> towards the library containing the dependency on PostSharp

Comment: I actually noticed this warning in the build output:

'2>C:\Users\stan\.nuget\packages\postsharp\2023.0.3\build\PostSharp.targets(387,5): warning PS0219: The targeting pack for platform ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1" is not installed. This may be platform PostSharp is running on, the target framework, or target framework of one of the references. Please install the appropriate .NET Framework Targeting Pack or .NET Framework Developer Pack.' , but I don't find any reference to 4.8.1 in my solution

Comment: That means that you have .NET Framework 4.8.1 installed and reference assemblies are not installed. PostSharp needs them for mapping types between the compiled assembly and the runtime it is running on. **You can install this using Visual Studio Installer, under Individual Components**. If not present, PostSharp will fallback to using the runtime assemblies, which may cause issues in edge cases.

Comment: I don't know where 4.8.1 is coming from, my project's TargetFramework is 4.6.2, I looked for tools to get a dependency graph, but couldn't find one telling me where 4.8.1 is coming from. Is there any way to override this so PostSharp uses the TargetFramework that is used by the rest?

Comment: The reason PostSharp needs reference assemblies for .NET Framework 4.8.1 is that this version is installed on your computer. PostSharp compiler needs reference assemblies for both the version of the target framework you're using (4.6.1) and the version it is running on (4.8.1) in order to work correctly. The lack of reference assemblies for the target framework (4.6.1) results in an error. The lack of reference assemblies for the runtime framework (4.8.1) results in a warning because it is needed only in several edge cases.

Comment: Are you still having the problem after installing the targeting pack?